# Visible binding is not working in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my code i am pushing an object on click of Add button which display an input field an d apply button. on click of apply button i write a function through which i am displaying my text and show field button. but i am getting an error "show is not defined" 
 here is my function

```
self.apply = function () {
    self.show(false);
    self.showFields(true);
};
```

addterm is here

```
self.addTerm = function () {
    var term = new Term("12");
    self.Terms.push(term);
    self.show(true);
    self.showFields(false);
};
```

Here is JS Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/b81mjt9k/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over your `Terms` using:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Terms">
```

The scope inside the `tbody` becomes the current `Term` you're iterating over. So when you write:

```
<input type="text" class="edit" data-bind="value: loanterm, visible: show"  />
```

Knockout is looking for `Term.show` which obviously doesn't exists. So you need to point Knockout to the root ViewModel using the `$root` keyword:

```
<input type="text" class="edit" data-bind="value: loanterm, visible: $root.show"  />
```

(Same goes for your `showFields` property)

See [Binding-Context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parent keyword.

```
<button class="button addNewButton" data-bind="click: $root.addTerm">Add a new Term for Loan</button>
<table class="termGrid">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="headRow headColumn">
            Term
        </th>
        <th class="headRow tools">
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Terms">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="tools">

            <input type="text" class="edit" data-bind="value: loanterm, visible: $parent.show"  />
            <strong class="read" data-bind="text: loanterm, visible: $parent.showFields" ></strong>
            <a class="button toolButton" href="#" data-bind="visible: $parent.showFields" >show Tiers</a> 
             <a class="button toolButton" href="#" data-bind="click: $root.apply,visible:$parent.show" >Apply</a> 

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b81mjt9k/3/)